# How to save and display previously entered values ​in the form fields?

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 `forms` per page. Here is one of them.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  
  <div>
    <label for="sum">Sum</label>
    <input id="sum" type="number">
   
    <label for="currency">Currency</label>
    <select id="currency">
      <option value="KZT">KZT</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label for="term">Term</label>
    <select id="term">
      <option value="1">1 month</option>
      <option value="3">3 months</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreditFilterForm(forms.Form):
    sum = forms.CharField()
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CURRENCY_CHOICES, ...)
    term = forms.ChoiceField(choices = PERIOD_CHOICES, ...)
```

**views.py**

```
CreitsListView(ListView):
...

def get(self):
    ...
    little_form = CreditFilterForm(self.request.GET or None, prefix="little")
    ...


class LittleFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CreditFilterForm
    prefix = 'little'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

Now, when the user entered the data and *reloaded the page* (without a submit), or when he simply *closed the page and opened* it again after some time - the *entered data disappears*.

How can I save and display them? It is necessary to use `caching`. Or store the entered values ​​in the `database`, and then substitute them?

Comment: You would need to add an onchange handler to the dropdowns, and keyup to the textbox and store the value in localstorage or a cookie, then set the selected values on page load

Comment: Do not tell me how to implement it? Or some example?

Comment: Thank you very much. `LocalStorage` fits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example.

```
function setVal(el) {
  var type = el.attr('type');
    if (type == 'number') {
      el.val(+localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))
    } else if (type == 'checkbox') {
        if (localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) == 'on') {
          el.prop('checked', true)
        }
    } else {
      el.val(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
  var el = $('#reservation').find('#'+ localStorage.key(i))
  setVal(el);
  var el = $('#big_form').find('#'+ localStorage.key(i))
  setVal(el);
}

$('#reservation').change(function(e){
  localStorage.setItem(e.target.id, e.target.value)
})

$('#big_form').change(function(e){
  localStorage.setItem(e.target.id, e.target.value)
})
```